# Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoException$DuplicateKey

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, email

I am trying to get mails from gmail and I am storing the message object in a mongodb collection "mails". I have created a Mail class and connected to mongo using spring. While adding messages to collection everything works fine and messages are getting populated in collection.

Before getting mail from gmail server,I am first searching it in my db whether the message is present,using messageNumber.For this iam using findOne() method.While doing this , I am getting the above mentiones error.

```
private HashMap<String,Object> getMails(Folder folder,int pageNo) throws MessagingException {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                SpringMongoConfig.class);
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx
                .getBean("mongoTemplate");
        ArrayList<Mail> mails = new ArrayList<Mail>();
        HashMap<String,Object> mailsAndPageNos = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        int messageCount = folder.getMessageCount();
        int from = (messageCount - (pageNo*10));
        int to = (messageCount - ((pageNo*10)-10));
        double totalPageNos = Math.ceil((messageCount/10));
        Mail mail;

        System.out.println("to---->" + to);
        System.out.println("from------>" + from);
        Message message;
        for(int messageNumber=to;messageNumber>from;messageNumber--){
            System.out.println("messageNumber-->" + messageNumber);

            //The line where I am getting error
            Mail dbMail = mongoOperation.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("messageNumber").is(messageNumber)),Mail.class);
                if(dbMail != null){

                    mails.add(dbMail);

                }
                else{
                    message = folder.getMessage(messageNumber);
                    mail = new Mail(message);
                    mongoOperation.save(mail);
                    mails.add(mail);
                }
        }

        mailsAndPageNos.put("mails", mails);
        mailsAndPageNos.put("totalPageNos", totalPageNos);

        return mailsAndPageNos;

    }
```

My Mail class

```
package model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "mails")
public class Mail{

//  private Message message;
    private String userName;
    private Address[] from;
    private Date sentDate;
    private Date recievedDate;
    private int messageNumber;
    private Address[] to;
    private String subject;
    private String contentType;
    private Part content;
    private Address[] cc;
    private Address[] bcc;
    private Address[] recipients;
    private Flags flag;
    private String fileName;
    private String description;
    private String disposition;
    private Enumeration headers;
    private DataHandler dataHandler;
    private int lineCount;
    private boolean seen;

    public int getMessageNumber() {
        return messageNumber;
    }

    public void setMessageNumber(int messageNumber) {
        this.messageNumber = messageNumber;
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

The error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoException$DuplicateKey
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:51)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1665)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1495)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:1302)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:475)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:470)
    service.ImapServiceImpl.getMails(ImapServiceImpl.java:66)
    service.ImapServiceImpl.getInboxFolder(ImapServiceImpl.java:102)
    controller.ImapController.getInboxFolder(ImapController.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
```

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Webclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>Webclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Webclient</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jackson.version>2.1.1</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev23-1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev86-1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.29</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lordofthejars</groupId>
            <artifactId>nosqlunit-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you miss `mongo-java-driver-<version>.jar` i your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Edit:

The Exception has moved in Version3 of mongo-java-api. See the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DuplicateKeyException.html).

You have to use a version 2.x

Comment: Hey,I have mongo-java-driver in my pom.xml file.
And it is also present in my .m2 folder.

Comment: Hi,I just edited my question to include pom.xml file